# Eliminar filas de una lista cuando pasen sus datos

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Buenas noches para todos, un gran favor necesito hacer lo siguiente:
quiero que luego de pasar las filas que tengo con Check en un datagridview C# se eliminen de la lista y solo queden las que no tiene el Check. para ello tengo lo siguiente ya hecho.
una lista del tipo tblProducto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como verán en la imagen los tengo en una Lista.
y también lo tengo como DataSource para el DatagridView de la izquierda de la imagen de mas abajo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

todo funciona como verán, y este es el código que tengo en el button que hace el envío

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in DataGridViewPreciosAntiguo.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(fila.Cells["Select"].Value))
            {
                AuxProducto objAuxiliar = new AuxProducto(); //ok
                objAuxiliar.ProductoId = (int)fila.Cells["Id"].Value;
                objAuxiliar.Codigo = fila.Cells["Codigo"].Value.ToString();
                objAuxiliar.ProductoDescripcion = fila.Cells["ProductoDescripcion"].Value.ToString();
                objAuxiliar.PrecioVenta = 0.00M;
                ListaAuxProductos.Add(objAuxiliar);
            }
            DataGridViewPrecioNuevo.DataSource = null;
            DataGridViewPrecioNuevo.DataSource = ListaAuxProductos;
            //ListaProductos.RemoveAll(x => x.Id == ObjectAuditRule);
            //DataGridViewPreciosAntiguo.DataSource = null;
            //DataGridViewPreciosAntiguo.DataSource = this.ListaProductos;
            //DataGridViewPreciosAntiguo.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

que es lo que necesito hacer. Es que los que ya pasaron o en este momento estan con Check se eliminen de la lista.
Tengo el código que esta comentado que lo borra pero no lo que están el en Check.
Por favor una ayuda para resolver este inconveniente.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda.
RM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todo tu problema esta en la logica de tu proceso.. leamos la logica actual:

```
//Para cada item en tu grilla antigua
foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in DataGridViewPreciosAntiguo.Rows)
{
    //nos fijamos si la selecciono
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(fila.Cells["Select"].Value))
    {
        AuxProducto objAuxiliar = new AuxProducto(); //ok
        ...llenamos el objeto
        //Lo guardamos en otra lista
        ListaAuxProductos.Add(objAuxiliar);
    }
    //Limpiamos la grilla nueva, seguimos dentro del for!!! o sea, lo hacemos en cada linea
    DataGridViewPrecioNuevo.DataSource = null;
    DataGridViewPrecioNuevo.DataSource = ListaAuxProductos;
    //Aca es donde re cargabas la grilla vieja, pero no se entiende porque dentro del for, y porque para todos los items y no solo los que estaban seleccionados
    //ListaProductos.RemoveAll(x => x.Id == ObjectAuditRule);
    //Seguimos dentro del for, recargabas la grilla vieja en todas las vueltas de tu for!!!
    //DataGridViewPreciosAntiguo.DataSource = null;
    //DataGridViewPreciosAntiguo.DataSource = this.ListaProductos;
    //DataGridViewPreciosAntiguo.Refresh();
}
```

Ahora, pensemos un poco la logica, primero queremos ver que filas estan seleccionadas, despues queremos sacar de la vieja grilla esos items seleccionados, y despues pasamos a cada grilla la lista que corresponde...

El codigo que sigue no esta optimizado, pero explica la logica del proceso como corresponde y deberia hacerse..

No querer hacer todo junto cuando uno no tiene claro el proceso es una de las mejores cosas que se puede hacer.. uno escribe un proceso, y luego lo va optimizando, sabiendo las partes que tiene.

```
//Para cada item en tu grilla antigua
foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in DataGridViewPreciosAntiguo.Rows)
{
    //nos fijamos si la selecciono
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(fila.Cells["Select"].Value))
    {
        AuxProducto objAuxiliar = new AuxProducto(); //ok
        ...llenamos el objeto
        //Lo guardamos en otra lista
        ListaAuxProductos.Add(objAuxiliar);
    }
}
//Ahora que ya sabemos los items marcados, los sacamos de la otra lista
foreach (AuxProducto a in ListaAuxProductos)
{
    ListaProductos.RemoveAll(x => x.Id == a.Id);
}
//Y ahora re armamos las grillas... 
DataGridViewPrecioNuevo.DataSource = null;
DataGridViewPrecioNuevo.DataSource = ListaAuxProductos;
DataGridViewPreciosAntiguo.DataSource = null;
DataGridViewPreciosAntiguo.DataSource = this.ListaProductos;
DataGridViewPreciosAntiguo.Refresh();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @gbianchi, me sirvió